# How do you 'continue' when the exception is in the actual 'for' statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, exception

Here's a quick example.
It's a recursive function (i.e. it calls itself) that tries to list the contents (`child`ren) of a directory (`parent`).

1. If the `child` is a *file* it just prints the file's name.
2. If the `child` is a *directory*, it prints the directory's name and tries to list *it's* contents as well, and so on.
3. If the `child` is a *directory*, but the user doesn't have permission to read it's contents, an exception (`OSError`) is thrown. So we wrap it with a `try:` and `except OSError: continue` to prevent the loop from terminating. It says:  *"When privileges are insufficient, don't stop; keep going; just shake it off and move on to the next one."*

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

def list_children(parent):
    for child in os.listdir(parent):
        try:
            if os.isdir(child):
                print(child)
                list_children(child)
            elif os.isfile(child):
                print(child)
        except OSError:
            continue

list_children('/home')
```

---

However, `continue` only works inside the body of a loop (e.g. `for`, `while`), what can you do when the exception is thrown by the actual `for` (or `while`) loop expression (i.e. the line immediately before the main body of the loop), like the `os.listdir()` function in the example above?

Comment: Just have a `if os.isdir()` before the loop?

Comment: assign the result of `os.listdir(parent)` to a variable and wrap that action in a try block

Comment: as an aside, you should probably just be using `os.walk`

Answer (score 3):

you could assign the result of `listdir` to a variable and wrap all that in a try block, if this fails with OS error then you wont have anything to iterate over so just return from th function. otherwise start your for loop with the try block inside it to skip

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

def list_children(parent):
        try:
            results =  os.listdir(parent)
        except OSError:
            return

        for child in results :
            try:
                if os.isdir(child):
                    print(child)
                    list_children(child)
                elif os.isfile(child):
                    print(child)
            except OSError:
                continue

list_children('/home')
```

Answer (score 2):

If the thing that you're looping over can't be generated, there's nothing to `continue` to (i.e. you can't go to the next iteration of the loop if there's no loop).  Just wrap the entire thing in a `try`, or maybe just wrap that first top level `listdir` so as to keep the indentation under control:

```
def list_children(parent: str) -> None:
    try:
        top_level = os.listdir(parent)
    except OSError:
        top_level = []

    for child in top_level:
        try:
            if os.isdir(child):
                print(child)
                list_children(child)
            elif os.isfile(child):
                print(child)
        except OSError:
            continue
```

Comment: I've never seen that `(parent: str) -> None:` syntax before